# Can I develop for iPhone with Xcode on 10.6.8?

Tags: ios, xcode, osx-snow-leopard

I am trying to get into iPhone apps and my 2009 Macbook Pro (running 10.6.8) is not capable of running the newest version of Xcode.

Do I need the newest version of Xcode to properly create an app? (I have v 4.02)

If so is a software update the way to go or will I need to upgrade the computer to run Xcode efficiently?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

WARNING! DON'T WASTE YOUR TIME!

**OS X 10.6.8 (snow leopard) is now TOO OLD to publish an iphone app.**

You'll need a new mac with OS X 10.8 (mountain lion). If the hardware in your mac won't support an upgrade to more recent OS X versions, don't waste your time. Apple have not maintained backward compatibility, so the necessary versions of Xcode or Application Launcher won't run on 10.6.8.

You can develop, test and simulate with your old mac, but ultimately  to build and publish your app you'll need a newer Mac.

Answer (score 1):

With 10.6.8 you can at least upgrade to Xcode 4.2 so you should do this. But you won't be able to work with any projects that include Storyboards or the new collection literals. You will be able to use ARC (modern memory management). You won't be able to use any iOS 6 features (max iOS version is 5.0 I think, maybe 5.1).

For learning this is fine, your main limitation will be opening sample code projects from others that use new features, you won't be able to run them. Also you won't be able to use 3rd-party frameworks targeted for iOS6 / OSX10.7+.

But your 2009 Macbook Pro should run the latest OSX.10.8.2 fine. I am running a 2008 MBP (6MB ram) with no problems. Then you can run the latest XCode 4.5.2 and be compatible with everything.

Comment: Okay great, well I will definitely consider the upgrade, but just to be clear, the new devices are capable of running the apps developed with XCode 4.2, but I just can't make higher performance apps correct?

Comment: @Ford - Yes that's correct. Although it's not so much about performance, more to do with features.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need the newest version of Xcode to create an app, but you'll need the newest version of Xcode to create apps that take advantage of newer versions of iOS.

Answer (score 0):

Yes You can Develop but in order to avail the latest developments and improvement it is advisable to upgrade.Upgrade usually makes the life of developers easy, though there is some initial resistance towards change

Answer (score 0):

Yes You can develop apps through your Xcode. The last version of Xcode is 4.2 for Snow Leopard. But you need to update your OS for develop for latest OS and device. Also Upgrade your OS, So you can use latest Xcode and get advantage of development tools